# Unable to change my keyboard layout in Archlinux/Cinnamon

Tags: xorg, arch-linux, keyboard-layout, cinnamon

I'm on Archlinux with Cinnamon. I would like to change from a french keyboard (fr) to a swiss one (ch).
So I edit my `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-keyboard-layout.conf` file:

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "evdev keyboard catchall"
    MatchIsKeyboard "on"
    MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
    Driver "evdev"
    Option "XkbModel" "pc105"
    Option "XkbLayout" "ch"
    Option "XkbVariant" "fr"
EndSection
```

But unfortunately, after a relog I'm still with a French AZERTY keyboard instead of a Swiss QWERTZ keybord:
`setxkbmap -print -verbose 10`

```
Setting verbose level to 10
locale is C
Trying to load rules file ./rules/evdev...
Trying to load rules file /usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev...
Success.
Applied rules from evdev:
rules:      evdev
model:      pc105
layout:     fr,fr,us
variant:    latin9,,
Trying to build keymap using the following components:
keycodes:   evdev+aliases(azerty)
types:      complete
compat:     complete
symbols:    pc+fr(latin9)+fr:2+us:3+inet(evdev)
geometry:   pc(pc105)
xkb_keymap {
    xkb_keycodes  { include "evdev+aliases(azerty)" };
    xkb_types     { include "complete"  };
    xkb_compat    { include "complete"  };
    xkb_symbols   { include "pc+fr(latin9)+fr:2+us:3+inet(evdev)"   };
    xkb_geometry  { include "pc(pc105)" };
};
```

I have the correct keyboard in GDM.

But if I use the following command:
`setxkbmap -model pc105 -layout ch -variant fr`
I manage to get the Swiss keyboard.

I suspect something from cinnamon.
If anyone has an idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally it was Cinnamon which overrode the Xorg keyboard layout.
As the keyboard section in the Cinnamon settings only contains the shortcuts settings, I thought there was nothing in Cinnamon to select the keyboard layout.
In fact, it was in the Regional Parameters section ...
So I changed the keyboard layout in Cinnamon and it works now.